# Mongo DB Data Migration

Tags: mongodb

We have Sharded Mongo Cluster.
However some documents are sharded and others are unsharded.

We are planning to migrate these databases to new cluster.
Please update if there is any process or steps to migrate the data from one sharded cluster to the other.

We have two secondaries and 1 primary for each shard,MongoS,3 Config Servers,2 Arbitors.
I understood that copydb can not be used on the sharded collection.
Please suggest if there is any other way.

Comment: You should really direct your questions which are not about programming but about administration of MongoDB to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are you migrating the whole cluster or just certain databases? There are [instructions for migrating a whole sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/migrate-sharded-cluster-to-new-hardware/).

Comment: Thanks for the link.We are migrating whole clustered database.